# How to make a return statement in python if the argument is a string that represents a valid integer?

Tags: python, integer, return

if I write a main program to test its functions def as_integer(an_object) and def main()

If the argument is a string that represents a valid integer return that integer. Otherwise, return the NoneType object.

Call the as_integer function for each element in the list: ['20', 10, len, True, '-six', '-10', '0'] and output the result object on its own line
I should get the following output:

OUTPUTS:

```
20
None
None
None
None
-10
0
```

I developed the following code but i'm still getting an error.

I tried only the first part of my code and got ['20', 10, len, True, '-10', '0'] to print as [20, 10, len, True, -10, 0] on separate lines. but without the quotes. Would that be a problem?

I'm unsure if to use the (isinstance) or (isdigit). I tried using the (isdigit) to detect if an_object is a digit or (startswith) a "-" but I would get an error. This is what i have so far. Also, thank you for your patience throughout all this.

```
def main():
    my_list = ['20', 10, len, True, '-10', '0']
    for an_object in my_list:
        print(as_integer(my_list))

def as_integer(an_object):
    if isinstance(an_object, (str, int)):
        return int(an_object)
    else:
        return None
```

I get this error:

```
#TEST 1#
main() returned None
inputs:

outputs:
**  ERROR  ** None
* EXPECTED * 20
None
None
None
None
**  ERROR  ** None
* EXPECTED * -10
**  ERROR  ** no line
* EXPECTED * 0
----------
#TEST 2#
** ERROR **as_integer(True) returned 1
* EXPECTED * None
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 3#
as_integer('43') returned 43
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 4#
as_integer('-50') returned -50
inputs:

outputs:
----------
#TEST 5#
as_integer(id) returned None
inputs:

outputs:
----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def as_integer(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            return None
    return None
```

This would return `None` for `as_integer(10)`, but maybe it's your usecase. Still you can expand the condition with `isinstance(value, (str, int))`, but this will let `True` be converted to `1` which is common and expected in many more programming languages. For fixing this corner case you could add `and value not in (True, False)`

Comment: I get this error: For the first digit 20 of my string

Comment: @Kaede if I understood you correctly, you don't get expected values. It seems like it's some kind of homework or online learning resource with tests. Therefore I can't really replicate what you are doing. But! What I've noticed, in the `main()` you're passing `my_list` instead of `an_object` into the `as_integer()`. This could be a problem. My implementation of `as_integer()` should produce correct outputs for your inputs. (besides corner case(s) I've mentioned).

Comment: @Kaede you're welcome. In case your question is answered, consider marking the answer correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of the function. You have to use .isdecimal to check if the object is or not a decimal. Then, you create a for loop inside the main function to call several times the as_integer function:

```
def as_integer(an_object):
if type(an_object) == str:
    if an_object.startswith('-'):
        newOb = an_object.split('-')
        if newOb[1].isdecimal():
            return int(an_object)
            #print(an_object)
        else:
            return None
    elif an_object.isdecimal():
        return int(an_object)
        #print(an_object)
    else:
        return None
else:
    return None

def main():
    my_list = ['20', 10, len, True, '-six', '-10', '0']
    for i in my_list:
        print(as_integer(i))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.